Changing a parent element css property based on href
This is a section of a navbar
<li>
<a href="#Menu_20" title="Accounting" >
<i class="fa fa-money fa-lg"></i><strong>Accounting</strong>
</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_21">
<i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-lg"></i>Income
</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_49"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Customers</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_50"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Aged Analysis</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_51"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Prepayments</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#Menu_52"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Documents</a>
</li>


and this is the associated CSS
.mcd-menu li ul,
.mcd-menu li ul li ul {
position: absolute;
height: auto;
min-width: 200px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background: #FFF;
/*border-top: 4px solid #e67e22;*/
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
transition: all 300ms linear;
-o-transition: all 300ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
/*top: 130px;*/
z-index: 1000;
/* == */
left: 280px;
top: 0px; /*<-------------------------- Set at 0px ------------- this positions the element - */
border-left: 4px solid #e67e22;
/* == */

}
  .mcd-menu li ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px; /*<----------------- Set at 25 px ---------------- this positions the pointer*/
  left: -9px;
  border-right: 5px solid #e67e22;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  /* == */

}
I can locate the href elements
$('a[href*="#"]').mouseover(function (event) {
var href = $(this).attr('href');
if (href == "#Menu_22") {
    $(this).parent().css({
        "top": "200px;"
    })
}

})
But can't figure out a way to change the css on li and ul elements. I will replace mouseover with document.ready, but at the moment it's handy to see if anything fires
Edit
Here is what I am trying to achieve the first image is with the standard CSS settings (0px and 25px) - the second one shifts the view up and makes it more readable - settings changed to -200px and 195px.



Well, there is no A element with href of "#Menu_22" in your HTML. Can you please put your code in a Code Snippet so we can quickly test it? Or at least pretty-format it with indentations so we can understand better. Also don't put a semicolon in the css() second argument, just "200px" will suffice.

Martin - thank you for replying. Yeah, the semi-colon was just me trying everything :-) - Basically "#Menu_22" is the same structure as "Menu_21" - I am trying to get a handle on the next nested ul comprising of Menus 49, 50, 51 and 52 and apply the changes. I have updated the question so that you can see what I am trying to achieve. The entire structure is generated from a backend DB so adding IDs to other elements will only take minutes if that is the way to go.

Your code is changing the property on the link's parent element - the <li>. Are you sure you're not trying to change the property on the link's sibling <ul> element instead?

Hi Richard - yes, I am - sorry I have changed it so many times just to see what changes I have lost track.

Peter -it's just a snippet as the complete menu is over 500 lines long - the actual full html has no errors

This should target the first unordered list below the selected anchor.
$(this).parent().children("ul").first().css({ "top": "200px" });

Rik - thank you, have marked that up. Do you also know how to set the second property (which is the marker arrow)?

Your answer gave me the clue I needed to get the other part - changed this in css - top: var(--vtop); and then this in jQuery to get over the "before:" problem -  $(this).parent().children("ul").first().css({ "--vtop": "175px" })
